# SharePoint | Filter a Calendar with a query string

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, caml

I am looking for a way to filter a SharePoint Calendar WebPart by using a query string.  It looks like the default "Query string (URL) Filter" web part doesn't work for this.

Thanks for the help,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on what you really wanted to achieve but try to check this out

http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

you might find CAML queries useful on your end... this might help :)

Comment: I wanted to be able to show the calendar items in a calendar view.  I didn't want to use CAML and xslt to just show the a list of the events but I think this is the only way.  Thanks Ian.